# nginx variables are empty when using custom log format

Tags: nginx, logging

I'm trying to implement a custom log format for my access logs in nginx. I specified my `log_format` and `access_log` in the nginx.conf:

```
http {

    log_format myformat '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

    server {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log myformat;
        ...
    }
}
```

The logs are indeed written to the correct file, but all variables seem to be empty. The file looks like that:

```
-  [] ""   "" ""
-  [] ""   "" ""
-  [] ""   "" ""
```

If I don't specify the custom log format, everything is working perfectly fine, this is what the log file looks like:

```
172.18.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2018:09:28:27 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
172.18.0.1 - - [04/Jul/2018:09:28:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
```

Does anyone have a hint what the problem could be there?

Comment: I've got the same thing in my reverse proxy setup.  Did you figure this out?  Strangely the default `combined` log format works, but no combination of a custom format including a copy of `combined` yields empty values for me too.

Comment: I was passing my nginx.conf through an `envsubst`, which tried to substitute all variables that start with $ with environment variables. That way all log variables got replaced by nothing and were empty. Stupid mistake - maybe it gives you a hint in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a `root` directive?

Have you tried using a different file path than the default one?

Any other server blocks you have might still be writing to that location but with empty variables if they are processing the request but not where the request is finishing.